# CustomFields attribute in LogstashEncoder is not working

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration, fluent

Currently, this is the setup we have:

currentSetup image attached.
[image: currentSetup]

With the above setup, we expect the serviceName to be captured as a searchable field in Elastic/Kibana. Instead, the field is appearing inside the message and that makes the field not searchable.

The work around we have is to add the service field as additional Field like below:

workAround image attached.
[image: workAround image]

The above is working and we can search the field in kibana. Do we know why the customField is not working as expected?

Thanks

Comment: It would be better to add your code as text, instead of images.

Comment: It was a weird format issue and that is why i have attached as a screen shot. Does that help?